# how to add to value of an input field with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a input field like below,

```
 <input name="update_price" type="text" id="update_price" value="£" size="8" 
        maxlength="8" />
```

I'd like to get some price value from the value of a select box and add it after the £ sign, how is this achieved in jquery,

```
  <form>
                <select name="select" id="select">
                  <option>Select your pizza</option>
                  <option value="6.65">NY, 10&quot;, £6.65</option>
                  <option value="8.95">NY, 12&quot;, £8.95</option>
                  <option value="11.95">NY, 16&quot;, £11.95</option>
                  <option value="3.45">Chicago, 7&quot;, £3.45</option>
                  <option value="6.65">Chicago, 10&quot;, £6.65</option>
                  <option value="8.95">Chicago, 12&quot;, £8.95</option>
                  <option value="11.95">Chicago, 16&quot;, £11.95</option>
                  <option value="19.95">Chicago, Beast 24&quot; x 18&quot;, £19.95</option>
                 </select>
         </form>



    $(function()
    {
   $('#select').change( function() {

    $('input[name=update_price]').val($("#select :selected").val() );
  });
   });
```

it works with the code above but the £ sign disappears, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past I have used a background image on the input box for the currency symbol. That way the symbol can look pretty, be left aligned (while the value is right aligned) and it doesn't get in the way of calculations.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

Are the encoding of file and page is same? If you want to use special characters like pound sign you have to save your javascript file UTF-8 (without bom character. You can use notepad++ or a similar editor for that)

Btw you specified an id for input, so why not using that for assigning it's value and last, you can use **this** when you are in the change function scope. See below

```
$(function() {
  $('#select').change(function() {
    $('#update_price').val("£" + $(this).val());
  });
});
```

Comment: For the pound sign, try Alt-Gr + 2

Comment: Also note that kara is using the id of the input not input[name=update_price]. I think this is cleaner and probably faster(less selectors).

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to put the Pound sign in the value tag of the options in the select box.

```
<option value="€ 6.65">NY, 10&quot;, £6.65</option>
```

But that might deliver problems when calculating with this value. 
Nicer is the following:

```
$('input[name=update_price]').val("€"+$("#select :selected").val() );
```

I don't have the pound sign on my keyboard, hence the € :)

**//edit**

```
<input type='hidden' name='shopping_cart_value' value='0'>

$('input[name=update_price]').val("€"+$("#select :selected").val() );
$('input[name=shopping_cart_value]').val($("#select :selected").val() );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can not put the pound sign in the value tag because I'm using a shopping cart and I'm using the value for that.also I'm using firefox and when putting the pound sign in the "£", some strange characters come up? why is that?

Comment: Those strange characters are there because of the character encoding of the pound sign. 

Try updating two fields. One to display the right price. And one used for the shopping cart. Like i did above.

Comment: I'm guessing you're a PHP developer `=)` In your last code example, you've got the following: `"€".$("#select :selected")`

Comment: Hahahaha Yeah that dot should be an + :)

Answer (score 2):

To get the pound sign try

&#163; or &pound;

also, check out this for more on these codes:
http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm